# http://127.0.0.1:8500/

Tags: internet, internet-explorer

I am trying to access the URL "http://127.0.0.1:8500/" for CFIDE/Admin on a remote system.

I repeatedly get the following error.

```
    Content from the Web site listed
    below is being blocked by the Internet Explorer Enhanced Security
    Configuration.
    If you trust this Web site, you can lower security
    settings for the site by adding it to the Trusted sites zone. If you know this
    Web site is on your local intranet, review help for instructions on adding the
    site to the local intranet zone instead.
```

I unblocked the site "http://127.0.0.1:8500/". Then I added it to Internet Explorer's Trusted Sites, then to its Intranet Sites list.

Do you have any suggestions or recommendations?

Answer (score 8):

You can't access 127.0.0.1 from a remote Pc. It's your local computer.

Answer (score 2):

1. 127.0.0.1 is your computer, not a remote one;
2. Have you tried using some other browser (Firefox/Chrome)?

Answer (score 1):

The 127.0.0.1 is a loop back address that connects to your local computer. Replace "127.0.0.1" with the remote system's IP address, or host name if you have DNS configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on your server you could disable the Internet Explorer Enhanced Security.  It comes enabled on Server 2008 by default.  Check out this [link on how to disable it from the Add/Remove Windows features](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/96159/how-do-i-turn-off-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration-in-windows-server-2008.html)